# UI Thread blocking during API calls - is AsyncTask usage correct?

Tags: java, android

I'm rather new to creating apps for Android, but what I am trying to essentially do is sync an API (using Volley) completely to my App in the first instance, and then periodically thereafter (I gather Volley creates new threads itself).

Whilst the app is syncing with the API the main UI Thread is getting blocked (I'm seeing a lot of "Skipped frames" in the logs). I have tried running the code to get the data and create in the database within an AsyncTask thread, and while I can see that the AsyncTask threads were created the Main UI thread still is sluggish.

I was thinking that since the initial call is within an AsyncTask, any sub ones will be within the same AsyncTask thread?

I'm also not 100% sure if the anothe rpage exists, whether I can execute another AsyncTask query from within doInBackground(), or if I should just call doInBackground inself?

I hope the below will be enough to get some help/pointers, but if any more is required, I will gladly update this question.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SQLiteHandler sqlh;
    public DatabaseManager dbm;
    public API API;
    private Handler handler=new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        API = new API(getApplicationContext());
        sqlh = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        dbm = new DatabaseManager();
        dbm.initializeInstance(sqlh);
        ...

        // start 5 seconds after loading, then run every minute
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){

                getChanges("thisApiUrl");

                API.processSyncOut();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
            }
        },5000);
        ...
    }

    private class getChangesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];

            final SQLiteHandler sqlh = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
            final DatabaseManager dm = new DatabaseManager();
            dm.initializeInstance(sqlh);

            JSONObject response = API.doAction(url, new API.VolleyActionCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onActionSuccess(Object response) {
                    ....
                    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
                        ....

                        HashMap<String, String> addRecord = new HashMap();
                        addRecord.put("id", dataObj.get("id").getAsString());
                        addRecord.put("data", dataObj.get("data").getAsString());
                        addRecord.put("updated_at", dataObj.get("updated_at").getAsString();
                        dm.createRecord(addRecord);

                        ....
                    }

                    if (!json.getString("next").equals("")) {
                        // if another page exists, go to it
                        getAPIChangesTask task = new getAPIChangesTask();
                        task.execute(json.getString("next"));
                    }
                    ....
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private Void getChanges(String url){
        getChangesTask task = new getChangesTask();
        task.execute(url);
    }

}
```

**DatabaseManager**

Just a side question, but can a writeable database also do reading at the same time? Thinking that I could probably combine both methods below?

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private int rOpenCounter;
    private int wOpenCounter;
    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase rDatabase;
    private SQLiteDatabase wDatabase;

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
            mDatabaseHelper = helper;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        rOpenCounter++;
        if(rOpenCounter == 1) {
            // Opening new readable database
            rDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        return rDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        wOpenCounter++;
        if(wOpenCounter == 1) {
            // Opening new writable database
            wDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return wDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeReadableDatabase() {
        rOpenCounter--;
        if(rOpenCounter == 0) {
            // Closing readable database
            rDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void closeWritableDatabase() {
        wOpenCounter--;
        if(wOpenCounter == 0) {
            // Closing writable database
            wDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public Long createRecord(HashMap<String, String> dataTable){
            String id            = dataTable.containsKey("id") ? dataTable.get("id") : "";
            String data          = dataTable.containsKey("data") ? dataTable.get("data") : "";
            String updatedAt     = dataTable.containsKey("updated_at") ? dataTable.get("updated_at") : "";

            // we don't want ID to be set, as probably will be therefore updating something
            if (!id.isEmpty()) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("data", data);
                values.put("updated_at", updatedAt);

                // insert row
                Long insertId = db.insert("this_table", null, values);
                DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeWritableDatabase();

                return insertId;
            }

            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Volley callbacks are executed on UI thread, not on background thread. So you are doing DB operation on UI thread. This would be much easier if you were using Retrofit, which allows synchronous API requests that are NOT put back on the UI thread when they are done.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So if in the callback it calls another method that is wrapped as AsyncTask, it would be fine?

Comment: Are you *forced* to use Volley? Because your control flow will be bogus if you do that. Retrofit is much easier to work with and [recommended by the official latest Android Architectural Components guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#fetching_data).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Not forced to, but I've put it in place already - perhaps I can look into Retrofit if it is better - is this http://square.github.io/retrofit/ the library?

Comment: It is the library - many thanks :)